# Problema con la animación del progressbar

Tags: javascript

Quiero usar cuatro progressbar y animarlos de tal forma que la barra se llene desde un valor inicial de 1 hasta un valor final marcado por el atributo value, pero tal y como lo tengo la barra no se llena.
Codigo HTML

```html
<div class="nivel-lenguaje">
    <div>
       <progress class="valor" value="85" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div>
       <progress class="valor" value="85" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div>
       <progress class="valor" value="85" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
    <div>
       <progress class="valor" value="85" max="100"></progress>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codigo JavaScript

```js
window.onload = function () {
    animateprogress();
}

function animateprogress() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("valor");
    var value = 1;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
        function frame() {
            if (value >= elem[i].getAttribute('value')) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                value++;
                elem[i].value = value;
            }
        }

        value = 1;
    }
}
```

**-- MODIFICACION --**
Modifique la función de javascript y ahora hace la animación, sin embargo no se detiene cuando llega al valor indicado en value.
Codigo JavaScript

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('valor');

    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        animateprogress(i);
    }
}

function animateprogress (i) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('valor');
    var value = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
        if (value >= elem[i].getAttribute('value') + 1) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            value++;
            elem[i].value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al hacer  `elem[i].value = value` estas actualizando el valor constantemente y por eso no se detiene. Podrías guardar el valor de `value` en una constante:

```
function animateprogress (i) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('valor');
    var value = 1;

// en max se guarda el value de 85 y se mantiene constante
    const max = elem[i].value 

    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {

//aqui se utiliza a max
            if (value >= max + 1) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                value++;
                elem[i].value = value;
            }


        }
  }
```